# Intercept destructured function parameters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Is there any way or pattern that would allow me to intercept destructured function arguments and do something with them before the function is executed, without knowing the argument signature beforehand? I.e. something like:

```
const add = ({a, b}) => a + b
const multiplyArgs = (fun) => (...args) => fun(...args.map(x => x * 10)) // Won't work
const res = multiplyArgs(add)({a: 5, b: 10, c: 20}) // 150, won't perform the multiplication on c
```

The only option I found so far is using a regex to get the arguments from the string representation of the function, but that's very messy.

EDIT:

The actual use case is this:

I have an object with RxJS observables/subjects, and would like to be able to call a function/method that would take in another function, pick the required observables from the object, combine them, and then pipe the function to the new combined observable.

```
const observablePool = {a: new Rx.BehaviorSubject(5), b: new Rx.BehaviorSubject(10)}
updatePool( ({a, b}) => ({c: a + b}) ) 
// In the background:
// const picked = {a: observablePool.a, b: observablePool.b}
// observablePool.c = Rx.combineLatest(picked)
// .pipe(Rx.map({a, b} => a + b))
```

The idea is to hide the implementation of accessing the observables object and creating new combined observables. The user should be able to chain simple functions whose results would get lifted into observables automatically.

I can do it by adding a `pick()` function, i.e. `updatePool(pick("a", "b"), ({a, b}) => ({c: a + b}) )` but that duplicates and decouples the argument names. I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: You could do this using the `arguments` local object, but since that does not exist for arrow functions you would have to construct your code somewhat differently.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I've been struggling with. The context is that the destructured arguments are RxJS observables & I want to hide the implementation of combining them into a new observable & mapping over it.

Comment: it's unclear what output you expect. `add` will only ever return the sum of the `a` and `b` properties of any passed object. Where do you expect to see `c`? Do you want all properties summed? If so you'll need to redefine your `add` function.

Comment: "*without knowing the argument signature*" - that doesn't make much sense. Why would you want to intercept the arguments, and do anything with them, if you don't even know what the arguments are?

Comment: @pilchard the idea is that the inner function could take any arguments it wanted by destructuring, and the outer function would do something to them before the inner was called

Comment: @Bergi Maybe you're right, I was just thinking something similar like higher order functions such as `curry()` or `flip()`. Those are also agnostic about the function arguments but do something with them (or technically with the function I guess, but close enough).

Comment: @AdamB `curry` and `flip` only do pass the arguments to the decorated function, they don't do anything (like multiplication by 10) with the values. And still, they require that the function has two (or at least a known number of) parameters, so the structure is known.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I guess decorating is another way of describing what I would like to do. You're right that `curry()` and `flip()` don't do anything with the values, although I would politely disagree about the number of parameter having to be known in advance - see e.g. https://mostly-adequate.gitbook.io/mostly-adequate-guide/appendix_a. What I want to do might not be possible/might be a bad idea, but even if you know of some neat alternative pattern that solves the problem please let me know!

Comment: @AdamB. Curry works on functions taking a pair of values as parameter(s) in traditional languages, and even in JS where this is variadic it needs to know the number of expected parameters (`const arity = fn.length;` in the code you linked). So your `multiplyArgs` decorator also will need to know how many arguments the wrapped function expects, and whether it expects individual numbers, or an object containing numbers etc. The proper solution would be to write different functions for different signatures. But I'm still unsure what problem you are trying to solve - please [edit] and elaborate.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think that is really not possible (apart from inspecting the function's code). Another problem you have is that you don't really know the name of the result (`c`) until you've called the function. I guess a better solution would be some sort of macro system, e.g. [sweet.js](https://www.sweetjs.org)

Answer (score 2):

For just one object argument, you could map over `Object.entries`.

```js
const add = ({a, b}) => a + b;
const multiplyObj0 = fun => obj => fun(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([k, v])=>[k, v * 10])));
const res = multiplyObj0(add)({a: 5, b: 10});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to do it only for the arguments that have been destructured? I.e. for `{a: 5, b: 10, c: 20}`, it would only perform the operation for `a` and `b` but not `c`? 

Sorry that I haven't been clear about this in the original post.

Comment: @AdamB. You can't easily tell which arguments are actually destructured without somehow reading the source of the function. Although using the method I showed here would also change c, it doesn't change the output of `add` since it never sees `c`.